# Android Alarm being cancelled when shutting down the app. Leaked IntentReceiver

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a problem setting my alarm which is to send a notification about an upcoming event. I call it from my class with these lines of code (so far it starts 10 seconds after the app has been launched, just for testing purposes):

```
public void initNotifications(){
        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        BroadcastManager receiver = new BroadcastManager();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("ALARM_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent("ALARM_ACTION");
        intent.putExtra("param", "My scheduled action");
        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        // I choose 3s after the launch of my application
        alarms.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, operation) ;
    }

and here is the Broadcast Manager class (separate file):

public class BroadcastManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(context, intent.getStringExtra("param"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent it =  new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        createNotification(context, it);
    }
```

I also has createNotification function, which works fine.

Now I added the following line to android Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="BroadcastManager"
            android:label="BroadcastReceiverAux">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ALARM" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

What happens when I exit the app before ten seconds pass is the following error code:

```
Activity com.mysampleapp.MainMenu has leaked IntentReceiver com.mysampleapp.BroadcastManager@3370c300 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                    android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.mysampleapp.MainMenu has leaked IntentReceiver com.mysampleapp.BroadcastManager@3370c300 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:960)
                                                                        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:761)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:2002)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1982)
                                                                        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1976)
                                                                        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:503)
                                                                        at com.mysampleapp.MainMenu.initNotifications(MainMenu.java:672)
                                                                        at com.mysampleapp.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:133)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6283)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2642)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2756)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5940)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
```

I honestly looked through couple of topics here on Stack but I couldn't find the answer that would fix it. I want my notifications to run even after the reboot of the device, but to this I want to move later, after I manage to display them just after killing the app itself.

Thank you in advance,
John

Comment: The leaked Receiver is not "canceling" your alarm. You have the wrong `name` for the `<action>` in the manifest. It needs to match the action you're creating the `Intent` with; i.e., `"ALARM_ACTION"`, in this case. Also, you're leaking that Receiver because you're registering an instance of it dynamically - with the `registerReceiver()` call - which you don't need to do. And, if you want to reset the alarm after rebooting, you need a Receiver setup for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast.

Comment: I corrected <action android:name="ALARM_ACTION" /> but what do you mena to change with registerReceiver()? Now it works, but I still get this error.

Comment: I mean you don't need that, since you're registering the Receiver class in the manifest. The dynamically registered Receiver instance is leaking because you never unregister it, but you don't really need it, so you can just remove that section of code.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. However, after reboot, I try to implement this in onReceive: if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.mysampleapp.BroadcastManager$createNotification");
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        } . Is the startService the proper way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do upon reboot, exactly. You don't mention a `Service` in your question. If you want the `Notification` to show immediately, just call your `createNotification()` method. Or, if you want to set the alarm again, you need to do the `AlarmManager` setup again.

Comment: Okay, I get it. But how to resetup the exact times I setup before? The system does not save them right? I need to fetch them from, for example, external data base online?

Comment: Yep, you'll need to track the times yourself, and a database is definitely an option (likely the preferred option, if you're gonna have a lot of alarms to track), but it doesn't have to be external. You can keep an internal SQLite db in your app. SQLite is integrated into Android, and there's a bunch of helper methods and classes available to handle db creation and access.

Comment: Thank you, last question - can it be accessed on reboot then?

Comment: Yep. It's persistent storage, just like saving a file. [Here's the intro](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) on the developer pages, and there are tons of examples here on SO of how to use it.

Comment: Thank you :)! This answer helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the AlarmManager like this, it's working for me:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BroadcastManager.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+10000, pendingIntent);
        }
```